# Combining multiple spring security authentication providers into custom single one

Tags: spring-security, spring-java-config

My goal is to make two step authentication with credentials. First step is to check whether the user with principal has a role in a special database table. Second is to perform standard ldap authentication.

What I need is to perform *both* checks together but a common approach with authentication providers is to claim the authentication success after first success from *any* authentication provider. So I decided to create a custom AuthenticationProvider implementation which calls for LdapAuthenticationProvider and then performs DB check logic, but it doesn't work since there is nothing to autowire with AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.

Please, tell me whether

1. The approch to solve such problem is rational
2. If it is rational how can I inject AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider?

Security configuration code is

```
@Autowired
private DBRoleAuthenticationProvider dbRoleAuthenticationProvider;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.ldapAuthentication()
            .contextSource()
            .url("...")
            .managerDn("...")
            .managerPassword("...")
            .and()
            .userSearchFilter("uid={0}");
    auth.authenticationProvider(dbRoleAuthenticationProvider);
}
```

Custom authentication provider is

```
@Component
public class DBRoleAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private UserHasRoleInDBService userHasRoleInDBService;

    @Autowired
    private AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider ldapAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        authentication = ldapAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(authentication);
        if (!authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
            return authentication;
        }
        try {
            String loginToSearch = (String) authentication.getPrincipal();
            if (!userHasRoleInDBService.userHasRole(loginToSearch)) {
                authentication.setAuthenticated(false);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            authentication.setAuthenticated(false);
        }
        return authentication;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `auth.authenticationProvider(dbRoleAuthenticationProvider);`
is defeating `auth.ldapAuthentication()`

You should customize the way you retrieve authorities for the authenticated user by looking at the doc of 
`userDetailsContextMapper(UserDetailsContextMapper userDetailsContextMapper)
and
ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(LdapAuthoritiesPopulator ldapAuthoritiesPopulator)`

of LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer